# CORS policy error when trying to call custom search analyzer of azure search from ajax or browser

Tags: javascript, azure, search, lucene, analyzer

CORS policy error when trying to call custom search analyzer of azure search from ajax or browser

I have azure search service enabled on azure account. Trying to search queries with azure search from client call or ajax and which is happening very smoothly. I have some requirement to analyze search query before searching actual search text, so I have created a custom analyzer which when I am trying to call from browser or ajax I am getting CORS policy error on browser.

Tried already:
I have enabled CORS for index in which i have created the custom analyzer
I have used npm library that is azure-search.min.js having function to call for analyzer (client.testAnalyzer): https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-search-client

```js
   //Sample 1:
  var index2 = AzureSearch({
                          url: k2,
                          key: k1,
                          version: "2019-05-06"
                 });
    var analyzerdata = {
        "text": searchTextData,
        "analyzer": sessionStorage.getItem('analyz')
      }
    index2.testAnalyzer("fastampsearchindex", analyzerdata, function (err, 
    tokens) {
        if (!isNullorEmpty(tokens)) {
            //phrases = data.map(x=>x.token);
        }
     });

   //Sample 2:
     var urlTokenizer="https://mysearchurl.search.windows.net/indexes/indexname/analyze?api-version=2019-05-06";
     var analyzerdata = {
        "text": searchTextData,
        "analyzer": sessionStorage.getItem('analyz')
    }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url2,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain:true,
        data: analyzerdata,
        headers: {
            "api-key": k1,            
            "Content-Type":"application/json"            
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);            
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, message) {
            $('.loader').css('display', 'none');
            var err = "Error " + " " + message;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            toastr.warning(err);
        }
      });
```

analyzer should be called from browser instead of application to avoid round trip to azure search service via web app service where application is hosted

Comment: Have you configured CORS policy on the index?

Comment: Yes gaurav i have enabledd cors in index for all origin for time being

Comment: Right now I have done the proxy pass till I get some solution from someone or from microsoft to deal this issue from client side